# Usar Sweet Alert en Php para borrar un usuario

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, sweetalert

les paso las partes del codigo en las cuales necesito ayuda, por un lado tengo un icono que llama a una funcion js al hacerle click y le pasa el id usuario que se recorre con un foreach.

```
<td><a href="#"><ion-icon name="create-outline" onclick="alerta(<?= $usuario['id_usuario'] ?>)"></ion-icon></a></td>
```

Aqui tengo la funcion alerta() la cual recibe ese id usuario y lo manda a traves de get a la pagina eliminarUsuarios.php mediante location.href, el tema que al hacer esto no puedo mostrar la otra pantalla de sweet alert con la confirmacion (por eso comente esas lineas)

```
function alerta(id){

    swal({
        title: "Estas seguro?",
        text: "Una vez eliminado no se podra recuperar",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((e) => {
        if (e) {
            
            /*swal("El usuario ha sido eliminado correctamente", {
                icon: "success",
              });*/
            location.href='eliminarUsuarios.php?id_usuario='+id;
        } else {
            return false
        }
      });

}
```

Aqui dejo el codigo de la pagina eliminarUsuarios.php, que recibe ese id mediante Get y lo pasa a la funcion borrarUsuarios, tambien dejo la funcion borrar usuarios

```
//eliminarUsuarios.php
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET)){
        $id = $_GET['id_usuario'];
        borrarUsuario($id);
        ?>
        <h1 class="titulo">El Usuario ha sido Eliminado</h1>
        <?php header('refresh:4; url=administrar.php');
    }else{ ?>
    <h1 class="titulo">Error</h1>
    <?php }  ?>
<?php
function borrarUsuario($id){
        $pdo = conexion();
        $sql = "delete from usuarios where id_usuario = :id_usuario ";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt ->bindValue(':id_usuario',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

Alguno me podria decir como puedo hacer todo en la misma pagina que tengo la lista de usuarios, osea que me genere el alerta, y al apretar el boton ok ejecute el delete, me muestre el tilde verde que diga "usuario eliminado" y me vuelva a mostrar la tabla sin ese registro que acabo de borrar. Desde ya muchas gracias.
Aclaracion importante: De js se poco y nada..

Comment: En vez de redirigir debes ejecutar una petición AJAX para eliminar el usuario y así podrás mostrar el mensaje.

Comment: Hola Triby, nunca use una peticion AJAX ni tampoco se como podria implementarla en el codigo y de que manera implementarla. Si me podrias orientar un poco sobre lo que tendria que hacer, te lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar una peticion ajax dentro de la promesa de la alerta y que esa peticion te retorne el mensaje que deseas imprimir en la otra alerta, dependiendo del caso, ya haya sido exitoso o haya sucedido un error, por lo general lo manejo con dos variables retornadas desde la peticion, una booleana que determina si la consulta se ejecuto correctamente y asi determinar que tipo de alerta mostrar al usuario si una de exito o de error, y otra con el mensaje que debera tener dicha alerta, adicionalmente puedes agregar una tercera variable para poder hacer debug encerrando todo en un try catch y retornando el contenido del mensaje del catch.

Comment: Hola! Suena bien pero el tema principal es que nunca use una peticion AJAX ni tampoco se como podria implementarla en el codigo y de que manera implementarla. Si me podrias orientar un poco sobre lo que tendria que hacer, te lo agradeceria.